# Switching between full site and mobile changes the tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, mobile-web

Now, it could be an issue with this specific tag, but I've found in recent days that switching from the full site to the mobile site while viewing 'questions tagged with c#' results in viewing 'questions tagged with c' instead.  Is this happening for anyone else?

Comment: Repo with Chrome 26.0.1410.64 on Windows 7

Comment: This is still happening? How many times must we tell devs that C# != C. Its not like they programmed the website in C# or anything...

Comment: Also reproduced with [tag:c#-4.0], [tag:c#-3.0], and [tag:c#-2.0].  Same behavior.  Switching to mobile changes to filtered tag to [tag:c], switching back to full site leaves the filtered tag as [tag:c]

Comment: And I also tried [tag:c#] and [tag:xml] on the full site, switched to the mobile site and was left with [tag:c] filtered.

Comment: Seems like it's an issue with the hash sign, then.  The redirect gets confused by it and chops off everything after and including that hash, so we always end up with c?

Comment: Just tested it with j# and visualj#, and it ended up trying to find questions tagged 'j' and 'visualj'.  It does seem to be that hash sign that's the culprit.

Comment: @RichardJRossIII it's not like `example.com/C` is the same as `example.com/C#`?! Oh wait, it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Root cause was [HttpRequestBase.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.url.aspx) really not wanting to keep `#` in a trailing position, regardless of whether it was encoded or not.

Comment: Easy to blame C#! ;)